# Como pegar um link json e usa-lo no php

Tags: php, json

Recebo o seguinte link json:

```
http://localhost/json/?conteudo={"Login":"otacio@mail.com","Senha":"12345","Posicao":{"Latitude":"-18.8693459","Longitude":"-41.955664"}}
```

Como jogo ele para o php abaixo:

```
<?php 


$valor = json_decode('LINK AQUI');                      

echo "<pre>";                       
print_r($valor);                        

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estrutura *JSON* está sendo passado por *querystring*, então você precisa usar a variável *$_GET* para pegá-la.

Exemplo:

```
<?php 


$valor = json_decode($_GET['conteudo']);                      

echo "<pre>";                       
print_r($valor);                        

?>
```

Comment: exatamente isso, obrigado!